# How to remove a 'branch' in tortoise HG

Tags: branch, tortoisehg

I accidentally updated to a previous revision, and committed from it under the default branch, causing 2 heads under the default branch. I want to move one of the heads to another branch. This head I want to move was made a couple transactions ago. How can I change the branch it is a part of so that I can push the other head to the server without a force push?

I have not pushed anything to the server so far. If it comes down to it, I can copy the files I need and reclone the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the history with the **rebase** extension. It's already installed, you just need to enable it (from File > Settings > Extensions in tortoiseHG). Inside tortoiseHG you can find it if you right-click on a revision, go to "Modify History", and choose "rebase". But for more control I recommend dropping to the commandline.

Let's say you have a revision `w` that's a new head off the default branch. (`w` might have descendants which will move along with it).

```
-o-o-o-o
    \
     w
```

Its parent should have been some revision `b` in another branch (not shown). Just enter:

```
hg rebase --source w --dest b --detach
```

That's it! It will rebase `w` and all of its descendants (if any), so that its new parent is `b`. It will be assigned to the same branch name as `b`, unless you add `--keepbranches`. The flag `--detach` ensures that you don't end up with a complex topology under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rebase
2. Graft (move to new place) + Histedit (kill old changeset)
3. MQ, if you know it (convert cset to MQ-patch, update to new parent, qpop, qfinish)